# Wsimport de múltiplos serviços iguais com várias operações desnecessárias

Tags: java, web-service, maven, wsdl

Em Java, estou usando a ferramenta wsimport. O processo funciona. Entretanto há alguns problemas.

Tenho que fazer o wsimport nos serviços de vários fornecedores diferentes (todos eles terceiros, não tenho nenhum controle sobre eles). Os WSDLs são quase idênticos, só mudando a URL do destino.

Cada um desses WSDLs definem um monte de operações/métodos diferentes. Ocorre que dentre esse monte de operações, apenas umas 2 ou 3 eu vou realmente precisar. Quase no final de cada um desses WSDLs há isso:

```xml
  <wsdl:service name="Exemplo">
    <wsdl:port name="ExemploSoap" binding="tns:ExemploSoap">
      <soap:address location="https://www.example.com/wsIntegracao/exemplo.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="ExemploSoap12" binding="tns:ExemploSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="https://www.example.com/wsIntegracao/exemplo.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

De um WSDL para outro quase nada muda. Em geral, a única coisa que muda são essas URLs que estão no trecho aí em cima.

Eis a parte relevante do `pom.xml`. Eu tenho isso para cada serviço/WSDL diferente, de forma que cada um deles vai gerar um JAR distinto (há um `pom.xml` para cada serviço, cada um em uma pasta distinta).

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>servico-teste.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlLocation>servico-teste.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                        <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}</wsdlDirectory>
                        <packageName>br.com.example.servico2</packageName>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Xlint:none</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

As diferenças entre um `pom.xml` e outro são mínimas. Praticamente apenas o nome do pacote a ser gerado e o nome do arquivo WSDL.

Como já mencionei, o processo funciona. Mas deste jeito, se eu tiver 20 serviços diferentes, serão gerados 20 arquivos JAR quase idênticos. Se cada um deles tiver 100 classes, isso vai gerar 2000 classes diferentes em 20 JARs, sendo que só 3 ou 4 eu uso efetivamente.

Assim sendo, faço duas perguntas:

1. Há alguma forma de se otimizar o wsimport de forma a precisar executá-lo apenas uma vez quando os serviços forem iguais ou suficientemente parecidos, onde apenas a URL no `soap:address location` varie?
2. Há alguma forma de se instruir o wsimport a gerar somente as classes necessárias para uma determinada parte do WSDL, e não para tudo que for referenciado no WSDL?

Comment: @RenanCarlos Rejeitei a sua edição porque ela não me parecia estar melhorando a minha pergunta em nada, apenas acrescentando formatações onde não deveria ter. Se você acha mesmo assim que a sua edição era válida, gostaria de ouvi-lo. De qualquer forma, agradeço a atenção e o empenho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [resposta do btafarelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/171541/132) me ajudou bastante, mas ainda não era a solução ideal.

Também, [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4178783/540552) do SOen me ajudou bastante, embora ainda não fosse a solução completa.

Primeiramente, eu peguei um dos WSDLs e troquei a URL lá colocando uma URL genérica, gerando no maven as classes da mesma forma como eu já fazia.

No Java, ao invés de instanciar a classe principal do serviço a integrar usando o construtor padrão, passei a usar o construtor que recebe uma `URL` e um `QName`. Esse construtor também é gerado por padrão pelo ws-import.

Ao invocar-se esse construtor, tal como na resposta do SOen, eu passo URLs que começam com `http://localhost/wsdl`. Dentro da pasta `META-INF`, então eu crio um arquivo `jax-ws-catalog.xml` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```xml
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog" prefer="system">
    <system systemId="http://localhost/wsdl/servico1.wsdl" uri="wsdls/servico1.wsdl"/>
    <system systemId="http://localhost/wsdl/servico2.wsdl" uri="wsdls/servico2.wsdl"/>
    <system systemId="http://localhost/wsdl/servico3.wsdl" uri="wsdls/servico3.wsdl"/>
</catalog>
```

Dentro de uma pasta `wsdls`, eu acrescento os arquivos WSDL que baixei de cada serviço. Essa pasta é colocada dentro do JAR/WAR gerado da aplicação. Esse arquivo `jax-ws-catalog.xml` instrui o JAX-WS a procurar por esses WSDLs localmente.

Desta forma, eu só preciso usar o wsimport uma única vez. Por fim, para reduzir o número de coisas desnecessária geradas, eu posso editar o WSDL genérico.

Answer (score 1):

Se você puder gerar em um jar só, não vai precisar se preocupar. Eu faço assim, tenho um jar somente com minhas classes dos webservices.

Então, tudo que é comum é sobrescrito fazendo com que as classes sejam compartilhadas.

Se quiser insistir em vários jars, eu fiz alguns testes e é possível, porém será necessário alguma "gambiarra" pra deixar redondo.

Conforme o link abaixo:

https://metro.java.net/2.0/guide/Compiling_multiple_WSDLs_that_share_a_common_schema.html

Você verá que se fizer um binding como o meu, o schema que é compartilhado irá pra um pacote especifico. No meu binding, os schemas estão dentro dos wsdls (atenção).

```xml
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">

    <bindings scd="x-schema::bons1"
        xmlns:bons1="http://www.dominio.net/services/metadata/v2.0">
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="br.common.metada" />
        </schemaBindings>
    </bindings>

    <bindings scd="x-schema::e"
        xmlns:e="http://www.dominio.net/services/errors/v1.0">
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="br.common.errors" />
        </schemaBindings>
    </bindings>

</bindings>
```

Mas não encontrei uma maneira de não gerar classes específicas, então aqui eu sugiro que você edite os schemas que serão compartilhados mantendo apenas o que você quer gerar, ou então, exclua as classes dos pacotes que você não quer.

Aí, quando gerar as classes específicas, aponte o episode gerado no xjc conforme o link.

Achei muito trabalhoso, mas já havia me feito essa pergunta e foi o mais perto que cheguei.

Comment: Ola, realizar a geração por operação é uma coisa que ainda não existe, se fosse por serviço ai sim temos alguns plugins, eu mesmo uso o [CXF da apache](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) mas mesmo assim ele gera classes para todas operações, se todos os serviços dele tem a mesma estrutura até poderia ser feito de usar os obejtos gerados e alterar o endpoint e o Qname, mas podem ter outras propriedades a serem alteradas, e se caso um dos servilços mudar já quebraria o contrato, o melhor memso é como você falou, tudo em um jar e deixar a geração automática cuidar de tudo.

Comment: Gostei da resposta. Vou testar amanhã.